# Check if current tab is active from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I have a page that contains an iframe. The iframe contains  JavaScript that should handle two cases: tab becomes active and tab becomes inactive. I have such code:

```
//by default tab is active
var currentTabIsActive = true;
 
$(window.top).focus(function () {

    currentTabIsActive = true;
    ....
});

$(window.top).blur(function () {

    currentTabIsActive = false;
});
```

But there is a case when this code behaves incorrectly. Consider a situation when one opens a page, iframe is not loaded yet but one changes tab to another. And in this case when iframe will be loaded (user is on another tab) JavaScript will think that tab is active but it's not. Any advice how to fix that without Visibility API and HTML5?

Comment: Not 100% with you but first thing come out of my head would to use an anchor in url like #tab-1 or use session. More reliable otherwise you'll have to either check parent nod or not to render your tabs until iframe finished loading.

Comment: May be there are some window object properties that change once tab becomes inactive?